# Is sequence is important to including jquery.min.js before jquery-ui.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I was creating the datepicker in angularjs, So I inclued following js files.
**1.** `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

**2.**`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

**3.**`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>`

When I include jquery before jquery-ui, every thing working correctly, please see demo [Datepicker is working](http://plnkr.co/edit/nP52npMZi80C8vo0kgmA?p=preview)

But when I include jquery-ui after then datepicker is not working, please explain this behaviour. 
Demo when datepicker is not working Demo : [datepicker is not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/xo5HmrIdAsrRFIRrEoBr?p=preview)

Comment: if you see in browser console in sample with `datepicker is not working` you can see error _jquery-ui.min.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined_

Comment: @Grundy thank for reply, But I am still getting error, please see updated questionthe sequence of including jquery

Comment: if you get error - just provide it

Comment: @Grundy  sorry, I just mistake, element: datepicker instead of element.datepicker, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**.

All the dependent libraries should be loaded first. As `jquery-ui` depends on `jquery`, it should be loaded before `jquery-ui`.